# Current induced in a loop by a magnet, how does energy "radiate away" as electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

I am currently learning about energy transfers and induction, and I am not sure if I understand the concept of energy being lost through electromagnetic waves

Consider the following simple set-up:

A magnet is brought near a conducting ring, setting up a current in it. While bringing the magnet closer to the loop, some energy is lost as heat in the conducting ring, but some energy is "radiated away" from the ring (as the texts I am reading often put it). I'm not sure if I am thinking about this correctly, but when I think of this simple example, I consider the changing induced B field created by the conducting ring as subtracting from the total energy of the ring + magnet by doing work against the motion of magnet. In my mind this is conceptually different than energy being "radiated away", as I can't see how the ring would have to do work to create electromagnetic waves.

Does this description accurately describe how this energy is lost from the system?

Comment: Where's the electric field involved in the other half if EM radiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Here's what you are missing:

When the magnet moves near the loop, it induces a current to flow in the loop and so the loop thus begins to create its *own* magnetic field which then starts propagating away into space. The sudden change in the magnetic field coming from the loop also produces a changing electric field in the space near the loop, and the result is an *electromagnetic wave* propagating away from the loop which itself is thus acting as an *antenna*.

If we monitor the electrical power flowing around the loop, we discover that some of it is being dissipated as heat in the loop by *ohmic losses*, and that the rest of it is being dissipated as electromagnetic wave propagation. This portion of the power loss is referred to as *radiation resistance*.